# How to load combobox once a button which scans ble is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm very new to tkinter framework and was wondering if anyone could help me with my issue. I'm trying to load the combobox once a Scan button is clicked. This Scan button basically scans for a specific bluetooth device and returns all the bluetooth device. Once scan is complete, it should load the combobox with the results. Then after selecting an option from combobox, i want to pass that value to another button function that connects to to the bluetooth device.

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.button_scan = Button(master, text="Scan", command=self.scan1)
        self.button_scan.pack()

        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.cb = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=self.box_value)
        self.cb.pack()
        self.cb['values'] = self.scan1()


        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def scan1(self):
        scanner = Scanner()
        devices = scanner.scan(5)
        data = []
        for dev in devices:
            scanData = dev.getScanData()
            for (adtype, desc, value) in scanData:
                if desc == 'Complete Local Name':
                    if 'Thunder Sense #' in value:
                        deviceMac = dev.addr
                        #deviceMac1= str(deviceMac)
                        deviceId = int(value.split('#')[-1])
                        deviceId2 = str(deviceId)
                        print(deviceMac)
                        data.append(deviceMac)
                        #data.append(deviceMac)
        print(data)
        return data


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm able to print the deviceMac and also the list but i just can't seem to load the combobox. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scan1` does not have to return the data. Just modify the value of `combobox` directly after scanning is complete.

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...

        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.cb = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=self.box_value)
        self.cb.pack()

        ...

    def scan1(self):
        scanner = Scanner()
        devices = scanner.scan(5)
        data = []
        for dev in devices:
            scanData = dev.getScanData()
            for (adtype, desc, value) in scanData:
                if desc == 'Complete Local Name':
                    if 'Thunder Sense #' in value:
                        deviceMac = dev.addr
                        # deviceMac1= str(deviceMac)
                        deviceId = int(value.split('#')[-1])
                        deviceId2 = str(deviceId)
                        print(deviceMac)
                        data.append(deviceMac)
        self.cb["values"] = data
```